# Is it possible to have run-time dynamic table updates to visualization using javascript interacting with postgis and geoserver

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, geoprocessing, postgis-2.0, google-earth

I have an idea of/have seen implementations, of dynamic map retrieval/updating using wms on openlayers by using updates to a postgis database which was hooked into geoserver and having a refresh policy. I have also seen examples done using cURL with php and python. Is this possible using JavaScript without using openlayers? The reason I don't want to use openlayers is because my "base map" is a google earth plugin and I've heard they don't really get along well.

In any case how would I update a postgis database which is connected to geoserver so that I can essentially move a point's coordinates and display this accordingly? And I know that using geowebcache is how geoserver updates the databases it is connected to, but I have heard issues regarding this before as such what was the process for making sure geoserver updates? Preferably I'd like to do this in JavaScript without some kind of wrapper.